# nested child object does not behave like its parent does

Tags: javascript, nested, p5.js

I'm trying to create a simple raindrop particle effect. The `Raindrop` class instances are represented by circles, whose radii increase frame by frame and their color fades creating a nice effect. To improve this a bit, I want to mimic the wave created when an actual raindrop falls into a puddle of water.

My thought process was to create a child  `Raindrop` when the parent's radius grows above a certain limit. The child should then create its own child when its radius grows above the same limit etc.

```
var Raindrop = function (x, y, radius, genCoefficient) {

this.position = createVector(x, y);
this.radius = radius;

//genCoefficient, aka generation Coefficient makes sure that each generation of raindrops
//changes faster than the previous
this.genCoefficient = genCoefficient;

//display properties
this.red = 0;
this.blue = random(200, 255);
this.green = 0;
this.strokeWidth = 10;

//growth/change coefficients
this.strokeWidthReduceCoefficient = 0.25*this.genCoefficient;
this.growthCoefficient = this.radius/random(10)*this.genCoefficient;
this.blueReduceCoefficient = (this.growthCoefficient/maximumRadius)*this.blue*this.genCoefficient;

//child raindrop
this.child = null;


this.show = function () {

    //drawing the raindrop
    noFill();
    stroke(this.red, this.green, this.blue);
    strokeWeight(this.strokeWidth);
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, this.radius);

    //changing the raindrop
    this.radius += this.growthCoefficient;
    this.strokeWidth -= this.strokeWidthReduceCoefficient;

    if(this.blue >0){
        this.blue -= this.blueReduceCoefficient;
    }
    else{
        this.blue = 0;
    }

    if(this.radius>=20){
        this.child = new Raindrop(this.position.x, this.position.y, 5, 2*this.genCoefficient);
    }

    if(this.child){
        this.child.show();
    }

};

};
```

The code that draws each frame is this:

```
raindrops = []

function mouseClicked(){
    raindrops.push(new Raindrop(mouseX, mouseY, random(10), 1));
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    for(var raindrop of raindrops){
        raindrop.show();
    }

    Raindrop.removeRaindrops();
}
```

A certain function makes sure that the original raindrop is removed when its radius exceeds a predefined maximum. This also ensures that children don't keep spawning forever.

All the changes happen in the `show` function. When a child is created, I would expect it to behave just like the parent did, the only difference being that each child's changes in radius and color are 2 times faster than its parent.

Things go as expected until the first child is spawned. After that, the child's radius remains constant and doesn't change like it should. I am struggling but have yet to figure out why this happens.

Comment: Children never behave like their parents ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Coding turns out to be a miniature society, doesn't it? :P

Comment: Is this using Processing.js?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question that does the animation, i.e. calls the `show` method for each "frame"?

Comment: @Barmar it's called p5.js, but it's essentially javascript's version of processing.

Comment: @trincot added, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: But could you add the code that shows how this code is *repeated*?

Comment: @trincot the framework i am using requires that i define a `draw` function, which acts like a game loop. I merely define in the function what will be drawn in each frame, and the framework makes sure it's called over and over. Thus, i don't have to use `requestAnimationFrame` because it happens internally.

Comment: OK, I see......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once the radius is over 20, you *always* create a new child which *replaces* the child you had created in a previous iteration. So that child never gets a chance to grow -- it gets replaced every time with a new version of it.

So I would add a check that there is no child yet:

```
if(this.radius>=20 && !this.child){
    this.child = new Raindrop(this.position.x, this.position.y, 5, 2*this.genCoefficient);
}
```

Comment: Is this really necessary? The parent calls `this.child.show()`.

Comment: this makes sense, but since i have a reference of the child in the main raindrop object, and every child has a reference of it in its parent's properties, shouldn't it be working?

Comment: You're right of course. The problem is something else: I updated my answer.